# how do I correct the typeorm errors with my select query?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am getting the following error with my query:
`Class constructor CitizenDTO cannot be invoked without 'new'`

I have tried finding information on the `.from()` syntax and I have not found any information oh what the first parameter should be.  I have a plain old javascript type, an arrow function, and a class as shown below.

```
    const lastProcessedAt = '2019-08-01';
    await this.getConnection();
    const results = await this.connection
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('*', 'citizen')
        .from(CitizenDTO, 'citizen')
        .where('citizen.cit_last_status_change_date >= :date', { date: lastProcessedAt })
        .getMany();
```

and the dto:

```
@Entity("citizen")
export class CitizenDTO {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public cit_id: string;
    @Column()
    public cit_uid_serial: string;
    @Column() 
    public cit_last_status_change_date: string;
}
```

I'm not sure but I think my `CitizenDTO` isn't designed correctly.

I found a few links, such as [this one](https://codeburst.io/typeorm-by-example-part-2-46946bf08233), but they didn't answer my question.  The [typeorm github](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md) shows the from being used this way but they did not explain the structure of their DTO either.

Comment: Two things.  I believe that `cit_id` should be a number since `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` uses an `int` by default.  If you want it to be a string, you can use `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")`.  I'm also not sure about the syntax in `.select('*', 'citizen')`.  Why not just use `.select(*)`?

Comment: I assume you meant `.select('*')` since that is valid js syntax?    removing the 'citizen' alias did not change or affect the error I am getting.

Comment: Correct, `.select('*')`.  What about the `cit_id` type?

Comment: it has to be a string since thats how its defined in the schema (which I cannot change since the DB is not mine).  I changed that column to `@Column` and it doesn't change or affect the error I am getting.

Comment: Why do you need to use `select *`? if you don't add any select condition it would select everything anyway, also I don't think `.from` is necessary you could directly use: `.createQueryBuilder(CitizenDTO, "citizen")` assuming CitizenDTO is what you're importing from the DTO

Comment: @Shinjo what does the CitizenDTO look like?  is my implementation correct?

Comment: I can't be sure what it should look like since you're the one making it. But I was implementing each DTO with `@ApiModelProperty` or might as well with no identifier e.g: `export class CitizenDTO {
    public cit_id: string;
    public cit_uid_serial: string;
    public cit_last_status_change_date: string;
}` since I separate entity and DTO.